# Build rcp application show JavaSE not found when change commons-collections to 3.2.2

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, rcp

When I build my rcp application, it will show this error:

```
Host plug-in JavaSE_0.0.0 has not been found
[java] [eclipse.generateFeature] Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied.
[java] [eclipse.generateFeature] Bundle org.apache.commons.collections:
[java] [eclipse.generateFeature]    Host plug-in JavaSE_0.0.0 has not been found.
```

I have only changed commons-collections version from `3.2.1` to `3.2.2`.
My java is `1.7`, i also tested java `1.8`, it has same problem. if i rollback the "commons-collections" to 3.2.1, it works.

Comment: Where are you getting this plugin from?

Comment: "Commons-collections" get from our maven repository, The problem is not here, because i also download from apache website and install in my local repository, it has the same problem, i also install "commons-collections" 4.1, it also has the problem like 3.2.2. but 3.2.1 is right, and when i execute in eclipse, it is ok. only when i build my rcp application by maven.

Answer (score 1):

apache commons-collection requires (see manifest.mf):

Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3))"

If you remove this, the pde - build would run.

The question is now: why does the pde build not recognize  JavaSE, version 1.3 ? We build this with

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)